# How to retrieve data based on inverseColumn data using CrudRepository in springboot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, crud, spring-rest

I have two tables i.e. users and events. Users table will be filled when new user will sign up. Later same user can create calendar events. so events table will be filled and users_events will keep mapping of events based on user.
I would like to find all events based on logged in userId. so here is query, it should return data based on it.
select * from events where eventid in (select eventId from users_event where id_user=x ). Here is my Users and Event Entity class.

User.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "family_name", nullable = false)
private String familyName;

@Column(name = "e_mail", nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
private String phone;

@Column(name = "language", nullable = false)
private String language;

@Column(name = "id_picture")
private String pictureId;

@Column(name = "login", nullable = false)
private String login;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(name = "birth_date")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;
   //getter and setter
```

Event.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "events")
    public class Event {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "eventId", nullable = false)
private Long eventId;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
private String description;

@Column(name = "startAt", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startAt;

@Column(name = "endAt", nullable = true)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endAt;

@Column(name = "isFullDay", nullable = false)
private Boolean isFullDay;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_event", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_event", referencedColumnName = "eventId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", table = "users", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<User> user = new HashSet<User>();
/getter and setter
```

EventRepo.java

```
   public interface EventRepo extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
Event findByUser(Set<User> user);
    }
```

I am trying to implement something, which can give me output of this query.
select * from events where eventid in (select eventId from users_event where id_user=x )
here is my implementation.any input please?

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Event> getEvents() {
    logger.debug("get event list");
    User x=new User();
    x.setId(1);
    Set<User> user= new HashSet();
    user.add(x);
    return (List<Event>) eventRepo.findByUser(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a following method to your `EventRepo`:

```
List<Event> findAllByUserId(Long userId);
```

And modify your controller to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Event> getEvents() {
    return eventRepo.findAllByUserId(1L);
}
```

Comment: it worked! Is there any rule to define method 'findAllByUserId' ? and what other field i can use from Users table to make query?

Comment: Yes, rules are defined [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). You should be able to use almost any field.

Comment: Also is there any way, while saving events data, i can just pass UserId instead of  all the existing column data of users table? currently i am doing like this:
title: title,
description: description,
startAt: startTime,
endAt: endTime,
isFullDay: false,
user:[{"id":1,"firstName":"Steve","familyName":"JOBS","email":"steve.jobs@apple.com","phone":"0033 1 23 45 67 89","language":"en","pictureId":null,"login":"steve","password":"steve","burthDate":null,"enabled":true,"authorities":[{"id":1,"name":"admin"},{"id":2,"name":"technical user"},{"id":3,"name":"user"}]}]

Comment: Yes, there is. What you have to do is create a separate class for events data like `EventDTO` with plain `userId` field, create a repository for user `interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository` and then in you service layer after reconstructing an `event` from `eventDTO` you can do `event.setUser(Collections.singleton(userRepo.getOne(eventDTO.getUserId())));`.